# Rounding $1731.9146$ to $2$ decimal places?

Tags: arithmetic, approximation, decimal-expansion

So, I got this number $1731.9146$ and I need to round it to **$2$ decimal places**. The answer should be $1731.91$, but I had always thought, for some reason, that the answer (if precise) should be $1731.92$.

I might have a misconception, but I always thought that a precise rounding had to consider all the decimals, and not only the next integer. Shouldn't I start rounding decimal by decimal until I reach to the desired place? For example.

1. $1731.9146$ → Round the penultimate decimal
2. $1731.915$ → Follow to the next decimal
3. $1731.92$ → End, since we reached the desired decimal place

Am I might wrong in my believe? If I am wrong, any idea where I could of have gotten this misconception? I been looking for a while and it seems I am wrong, but I don't know why I can shake the feeling I got this from some chemistry class in my Uni.

Comment: You are wrong in your method.  That is what you should not do.  Instead round all at once: if you have $1731.915 \le x \lt 1731.925$ then round to $1731.92$ while if you have   $1731.905 \le x \lt 1731.915$  then round to $1731.91$.  Here $x=1731.9146 <  1731.915$ so round to $1731.91$

Comment: In particular, to "consider all the decimals" like that incorrectly rounds up all numbers with fractional part between 4/9 and 1/2. It may also be worth thinking about "rounding" in this way but in binary instead of decimal: then, any fractional part not exactly equal to zero will be "rounded" to 1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally speaking, "rounding" a number means mapping that number to its nearest neighbor in a smaller set of numbers.  The goal is the minimize the error between the original number and the approximation obtained by rounding.

For example, if I want to round $\pi$ to the nearest integer, I might note that $\pi$ is between $3$ and $4$, and then further note that $\pi$ is *closer* to $3$ than to $4$:  roughly speaking,
$$ |\pi - 3| \approx 0.14 \qquad\text{and}\qquad |\pi - 4| \approx 0.86, $$
where $|a-b|$ (the absolute value of the difference) gives the distance between two numbers.  Since $0.14 < 0.86$, $\pi$ is rounded down to $3$.

Something similar occurs in the example given in the original question.  The goal is to round a number to the nearest hundredth.  We might immediately note that
$$1731.91 < 1731.9146 < 1731.92, $$
so it will get rounded to one of those two numbers.  Then observe that
$$ |1731.9146 - 1731.91| = 0.0046 \qquad\text{and}\qquad |1731.9146 - 1731.92| = 0.0054. $$
Since $0.0046 < 0.0054$, the number is rounded to $1731.91$, as this minimizes the error between the original number and the approximation.

---

As to *why* it is sufficient to look only at the digit that is directly to the right of the desired level of precision, the following may be helpful:

To simplify the discussion, suppose that the goal is to round a number between $0$ and $1$ to either $0$ or $1$.  The same idea can be extended to rounding numbers to the nearest integer, or to other decimal places.  On the number line, these are the numbers

[image]

Any number $N < 1/2$ rounds down to $0$, and any number $N > 1/2$ rounds up to $1$ (if $N$ happens to be *exactly* $1/2$, we have to make a decision about how to round it—the usual convention is to always round $0.5$ up to $1$, but there are other conventions, e.g. banker's rounding).

Notice that if $N < 1/2$, then $N$ can be written in decimal form as
$$ 0.dxxx\dotso, $$
where $d$ (the digit in the tenths place) is less than $5$.  The remaining digits farther to the right are irrelevant, and could be anything at all.  Thus if the digit in the tenths place is less than $5$, round down.

On the other hand, if $N > 1/2$, then $N$ can be written in decimal form as
$$ 0.dxxx\dotso, $$
where $d$ is at least $5$ (greater than or equal to $5$).  Thus if the digit in the tenths place is $5$ or greater, round up.

Comment: That's a great answer. Just to complement it: as far as the procedure goes, you just see that the digit is $4$ and therefore we round down. There's nothing more to it. The fact that in $.914$ the third digit is $4$ means we're going to be closer to $.91$ than to $.92$.

Comment: @Snaw I included some discussion.

Comment: Technically, you can't round a decimal just by looking at finitely many digits. For example, if for each $k∈ℕ^+$ the $k$-th digit is $9$ if $[(k-1)^2,k^2]$ includes a prime and is $4$ otherwise, then the digits are $0.4999...$ and you (probably) cannot provably determine whether rounding to integer (i.e. $0$ decimal places) gives $0$ or $1$. But practically, this is irrelevant to the asker's conceptual issue so it's just for your laughs. =P